# Method to see if a character is in an array of Characters

Tags: java, arrays

I have these two methods- My code doesn't seem to be working as planned

What is is supposed to do is- Go through the array of characters- If there's not another character the same in the array, it is supposed to add itself to the index variable-

This is my comparing method

```
private boolean isValid(char c) {
    for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        if(Arrays.asList(letters).equals(c)) {
            return false; //Not valid
        }   
    } 
    return true;
```

Full code is below though

```
public void generate(String first, String second) {

    tempString = new StringBuilder(first+second).reverse();     
    letters = new char[tempString.length()];

    for(int i = 0; i < tempString.length(); i++) {
        letters[i]= tempString.charAt(i);       

        if(isValid(tempString.charAt(i))) {
            index += i;
        }           
    } 

}



private boolean isValid(char c) {
    for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        if(Arrays.asList(letters).equals(c)) {
            return false; //Not valid
        }   
    } 
    return true;


}
```

Comment: could you be more clear on what you want or where it's giving you an error?

Comment: `if(Arrays.asList(letters).equals(c)) {` You convert the whole array into a list and check if the whole list is equal to a single char? What?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to convert to a `List` (and a `List` is not a primitive `char`), you can use `==` for comparing primitive values (such as your `char`s). Something like,

```
private boolean isValid(char c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        if (letters[i] == c) {
            return false;
        }
    } 
    return true;
}
```

**or** with an enhanced [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) like

```
private boolean isValid(char c) {
    for (char letter : letters) { // <-- for each letter in letters.
        if (letter == c) {        // <-- if the letter is equal to the argument.
            return false;
        }
    } 
    return true;
}
```

You should also test for *validity* before adding to the array like

```
if (isValid(tempString.charAt(i))) {
    letters[index] = tempString.charAt(i);       
    index++;
}
```

Comment: If i test for Validity before- It doesn't store all the characters in the array- I need all the characters - If a character matches, i am supposed to return the index which the first character had- say if i input heh It should return index = 1 because 0 for h - 1 for e - 0 for h again

Comment: Then you should return the `index` instead of a `boolean` from `isValid` (return `-1` if it isn't found, and check for that condition).

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.asList(letters).equals(c)` is comparing the list to the character (Is the list equal to this character which is not what you want.

To find if a character is in the string you can instead do

`string.indexOf('a')` which will return -1 if the character is not present and >= 0 if it is in the string.